# IOS video player samples

Tags: ios, open-source, video-player

Hello I would like to add a few features to a video player, however I do not have enough time for writing the player itself. So does anyone know any open-sourced video player that plays .MOV extension videos through internet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of open source video players available that you can check out. Here are some links:

- http://openvideoplayer.sourceforge.net/
- http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ios.html
- https://github.com/ign/VideoPlayerKit

These should get you started but be aware that groking the code may take some time.

Comment: Thanks, I wish you gave this answer a year ago.